# How to format Python user input as time then subtract from that variable?

Tags: python, datetime, input, time

I'm trying to make a script for myself that helps me plan my sleep around a wildly variable work schedule.

I'd like to input to the script:

1. When I'm scheduled to be at work
2. If I'd like to be early to work and if so: how early I'd like to arrive at work
3. How long my expected transit time will be
4. How long it takes me to "wake up" and prepare for work
5. How many hours of sleep I'd like

The desired end result is for the script to tell me:

1. What time I should go to bed
2. What time I should wake up
3. When I should be leaving my house to head to work to arrive x minutes early

I'm trying to read the docs on datetime and time within Python 3 but it has been difficult so far. The math I currently have written doesn't account for rounding 60 minutes into an hour so my results are incorrect/inaccurate.

What I have so far obviously doesn't work but should give an indication of my logic so far:

```
print("SLEEP CALCULATOR v0.1\n")

print("What time do you need to be at work?")
work_time = int(input("Enter time in 24h format (0500, 0800, 1400): "))

print("\nHow many minutes does it take you to get to work?")
transit_time = int(input())

print("\nWould you like to arrive at your workplace early?")
early_choice = input("Yes or No: ")
# how to tell if the user wants to arrive early (below)
while True:
    if early_choice == "yes" or "Yes":
        print("\nHow early would you like to arrive to your workplace?")
        early_time = int(input("In minutes: "))
        break
    elif early_choice == "no" or "No":
        break
    elif early_choice != "yes" or "Yes" or "no" or "No":
        print("\nPlease enter yes or no!")

print("How much time do you need to wake up and prepare for work?")
wake_time = int(input("(In minutes): \n"))

print("Lastly, how many hours of sleep do you desire?")
sleep_time = int(input("(In hours): \n"))

bed_time = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time) - (wake_time) - (sleep_time * 60)
wake_up = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time) - (wake_time)
leave_by = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time)
work_arrival = work_time - (early_time)

print(
    "You need to go to bed at {}, wake up at {}, leave the house by {}, to get to work by {}!".format(
        bed_time, wake_up, leave_by, work_arrival
    )
)
```

Comment: Do you need only hours? (21.00) or hours with minutes? (21.13)

Comment: Hours with minutes preferably.

Comment: I almost finished, but I  have problems with minutes. It prints 21.5, not 21.30

Comment: Thank you for this question, I learned something new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You're going to want to look into Python's datetime library

Here's a quick demo based on your example:

```
work_time = datetime.strptime('2020-08-07 09:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
transit_time = timedelta(hours=1)
early_time = timedelta(hours=0) # Not arriving early
sleep_time = timedelta(hours=8)
wake_time = timedelta(hours=1)


bed_time = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time) -  (sleep_time)
wake_up = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time) - (wake_time)
leave_by = work_time - (transit_time) - (early_time)
work_arrival = work_time - (early_time)

print(
    "You need to go to bed at {}, wake up at {}, leave the house by {}, to get to work by {}!".format(
        bed_time, wake_up, leave_by, work_arrival
    )
)
```

When it comes to handling input, here's an example of how it can be done:

```
>>> work_time = work_time = datetime.strptime(('2020-08-07 ' + input("Enter time in 24h format (0500, 0800, 1400): ")), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Enter time in 24h format (0500, 0800, 1400): 09:00:00
>>> print(work_time)
2020-08-07 09:00:00
>>>
```

Comment: I've been reading into datetime and time libraries and so far I've found nothing that covers user input or simple subtraction from a user-given time. It appears all datetime documentation involves using the current time or a current timestamp which I don't need for this particular use.

Comment: I modified my example to your scenario and added a tidbit on taking in user input at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is without any libraries, only code :)

```
print("SLEEP CALCULATOR v0.2 by Alex Zab \n")
    
work_time = int(input("What time do you need to be at work? \n Enter time in 24h format (05, 08, 14): \n"))
while True:
    if work_time > 24:
        print("Please enter time in 24h format (05, 08, 14): \n")
        work_time = int(input("What time do you need to be at work? \n Enter time in 24h format (05, 08, 14): \n"))
    else:
        break
transit_time = int(input("How many minutes does it take you to get to work? \n"))
while True:
    if transit_time > (work_time*60):
        transit_time = int(input("How many minutes does it take you to get to work? \n"))
    else:
        break
early_choice = input("Would you like to arrive at your workplace early? \n y or n: ")
while True:
    if early_choice == "y":
        print("How early would you like to arrive to your workplace?")
        early_time = int(input("In minutes: "))
        break
    elif early_choice == "n":
        early_time = 0
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter y or n!")
        early_choice = input("Would you like to arrive at your workplace early? \n y or n: ")

wake_time = int(input("How much time do you need to wake up and prepare for work? (In minutes): \n"))
while True:
    if wake_time > (work_time*60):
        wake_time = int(input("How much time do you need to wake up and prepare for work? (In minutes): \n"))
    else:
        break
sleep_time = int(input("Lastly, how many hours of sleep do you desire? (In hours): \n"))

bed_time = (work_time*60) - (transit_time + early_time + wake_time) - (sleep_time*60)
wake_up = (work_time*60) - (transit_time + early_time + wake_time)
leave_by = (work_time*60) - (transit_time + early_time)
work_arrival = (work_time*60) - early_time

print("You should arrive at " + str(work_arrival//60) + ":" + str(work_arrival%60) + " o'clock")
print("You need to leave house at " + str(leave_by//60) + ":" + str(leave_by%60) + " o'clock")
print("You need to wake up at " + str(wake_up//60) + ":" + str(wake_up%60) + " o'clock")
if work_time > 12:
    print("You need to go to bed at " + str(int(bed_time)//60) + ":" + str(int(bed_time)%60) + " o'clock")
else:
    bed_time = str(bed_time).replace("-", "")
    import math
    bed_time_hrs = 24 - int(bed_time)/60
    print("You need to go to bed at " + str(math.floor(bed_time_hrs)) + ":" + str(60 - int(bed_time)%60) + " o'clock")
```

You are welcome!